# STM32, variable stored in flash could not be updated in other file

Tags: c, linker, sections, flash-memory, stm32f4

I use a STM32F411RE.
Since I've no more memory in my RAM. I decided to store large variable in my flash. For that I created a section in `section.ld`.

```
 .large_buffer: ALIGN(4)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
        *(.large_buffer.large_buffer.*)
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } >FLASH
```

In the `main.c` file, I declare the variable as follow :

```
uint8_t buffer[60 * 200] __attribute__ ((section(".large_buffer"), used));
```

At this point everything is OK, the buffer is not stocked in the RAM (bss), I can access it and rewrite it.

```
buffer[25] = 42;
printf("%d\n", buffer[25]); // 42
```

The problem comes when I want to edit the variable from an other file.

`main.c`

```
uint8_t buffer[60 * 200] __attribute__ ((section(".large_buffer"), used));

int main()
{
  myFunc(buffer);
}
```

`other.c`

```
myFunc(uint8_t* buffer)
{
    buffer[25] = 42;
    printf("%d\n", buffer[25]); // 0
}
```

`buffer` never change in another file (passed as parameter).

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to flash memory the same way as you write to RAM, because of physical design of flash memories. To be exact you need to erase sector/page (let's say ~ 1-4kB, it's specified in your MCU datasheet). The reason is that flash are made that they retain state even if they're not powered, whenever you want to change any bit from value 0 -> 1 you need to erase whole sector (After erase all of bits will be set to 1).

So you cannot use Flash as data memory, what you could do is use Flash as storing variables that are const (read-only) value, so any look-up tables will perfectly fit in there (usually compilers when you stat variable to const will put them inside of flash). How to write to flash you can read in Reference Manual of your MCU.

Comment: Thank for answering. Does storing buffer (that needs to be R/W often) in flash is a good solution ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as viable solution, first thing is that you need to save RAM to be able to first read then write flash. Write/Erase is much slower than read, and compared to RAM writing/erasing flash is longer. Plus there's limit on how many erase cycles you can do, usually something around 100k cycles.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem. At this point, I'm stuck cause I can't save ram. What could be a solution ? What optimisation are relevant ?

Comment: Possible solutions are:
- Move some read-only variables to const and store them in flash.
- Add SRAM as additional device to your system, STM32F4 got FMC peripheral which allows you to map external SRAM and use it the same way as internal.
- Use bigger MCU with bigger RAM

Comment: Or

- Optimise your software, find some places you could downsize, change protocol maybe to less resource needed. Find the way how to store information in shorter way let's say instead of using 32bit variable some places pack it to 8bit. If in some places you use just boolean (it's essentially storing 8 bits at least, so you could use 8 bit variable and bit mask it to store more than 1 flag.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look